# Parse Swift Saving Multiple Objects

Tags: swift, parse-platform, import, upload

`Parse` and `Swift 3.0`

I am trying to save multiple data one at a time but all the code does is that it saves every file to the same `ObjectId`. Hence overriding the previous saves. I am not very experience in coding and kind of lost. If there is a better way to do this I am open to suggestions. If you need anymore information I would gladly provide it.

```
func importToParse() {
    var i = 1
    var data = PFObject(className:"Annotation")
    for dataFromDict in dataDict {
        data["title"] = dataFromDict["title"]
        data["place"] = dataFromDict["place"]
        data["phoneNumber"] = "+9" + (dataFromDict["phoneNumber"]?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))!
        data["thingsToEat"] = dataFromDict["thingsToEat"]
        data["coordinates"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: (dataFromDict["lat"] as! NSString).doubleValue,longitude: (dataFromDict["long"] as! NSString).doubleValue)
        data.saveInBackground(block:) {
            (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.
                print("Finished #" + String(i))
                i += 1
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the object inside the loop

```
func importToParse() {
    var i = 1
    for dataFromDict in dataDict {
        var data = PFObject(className:"Annotation")
        data["title"] = dataFromDict["title"]
        data["place"] = dataFromDict["place"]
        data["phoneNumber"] = "+9" + (dataFromDict["phoneNumber"]?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))!
        data["thingsToEat"] = dataFromDict["thingsToEat"]
        data["coordinates"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: (dataFromDict["lat"] as! NSString).doubleValue,longitude: (dataFromDict["long"] as! NSString).doubleValue)
        data.saveInBackground(block:) {
            (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.
                print("Finished #" + String(i))
                i += 1
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.